# AWS CodeDeploy error - The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

i am trying to deploy the python application through code-deploy to the ec2 instances
but during deployment i am facing this error

> The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this
> location: /home/ubuntu/yello/manage.py

attaching my appsecfile also tried with overwrite but no luck

```
version: 0.0
    os: linux
    files:
      - source: /
        destination: /home/ubuntu/yello
        overwrite: true
    hooks:
      AfterInstall:
    - location: script/services.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
```

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error so AWS public docs has a section for the same.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-same-files-different-app-name

Basically when creating the deployment, you need to select `Overwrite the content` option so the deployment does not fail (default behaviour). Details here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-rollback-and-redeploy.html#deployments-rollback-and-redeploy-content-options

The default behaviour prevents two Deployments from two different CodeDeploy "Applications" writing the same file and possibly causing some sort of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/www/your-directory/public/funnel_webhooks/test/

sudo rm -rf clickfunnel.txt
```

After removing this file please release the change in the code pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can specify file_exists_behavior in your appspec file. Allowed values are DISALLOW, OVERWRITE, or RETAIN.

```
version: 0.0
    os: linux
    files:
      - source: /
        destination: /home/ubuntu/yello
    file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
```